# Icons not showing in ckeditor 4 in react js

Tags: html, reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

When I add i tag it doesn't work in ckeditor but it shows output when we print the html given by ckeditor.
I want that a preview should be shown in ckeditor itself for icons just like image and other tags

[this image shows that i have added icon in source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INTpu.png)

[but it doesn't reflect here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlwdN.png)

[but it is shown when html is rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhLJ2.png)